# define a variable in a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a sequence of numbers in a range from 65-60 . In each step we diminish 1/12

```
[1] 65.00000 64.91667 64.83333 64.75000 64.66667 64.58333 64.50000 64.41667 64.33333 64.25000 64.16667
[12] 64.08333 64.00000 63.91667 63.83333 63.75000 63.66667 63.58333 63.50000 63.41667 63.33333 63.25000
[23] 63.16667 63.08333 63.00000 62.91667 62.83333 62.75000 62.66667 62.58333 62.50000 62.41667 62.33333
[34] 62.25000 62.16667 62.08333 62.00000 61.91667 61.83333 61.75000 61.66667 61.58333 61.50000 61.41667
[45] 61.33333 61.25000 61.16667 61.08333 61.00000 60.91667 60.83333 60.75000 60.66667 60.58333 60.50000
[56] 60.41667 60.33333 60.25000 60.16667 60.08333 60.00000
```

For every step obove we will compute a function.

So a for-loop is created with the following code:

```
a <- seq(65, 60, (-1/12))
v <- a*0
w <- a*0
mu10<-0.0067
mu12<-0.5
mu20<-1.03*mu10
mu21<-3
r<-log(1+0.01)
b1<-(-1500)
b2<-25000*0.15*12
c10<-45000*10
c20<-45000*10
h<-1/12

v[1] <- h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)
w[1] <- h*(b2+mu20*c20+mu21)
for (t in 2:length(a)){
  v[t] <- v[t-1]+h*(-r*v[t-1]+b1+mu10*(c10-v[t-1])+mu12*(w[t-1]-v[t-1]))
  w[t] <- w[t-1]+h*(-r*w[t-1]+b2+mu20*(c20-w[t-1])+mu21*(v[t-1]-w[t-1]))
}
```

What we wanted to do here was to calculate the value of the function at age 60 by calculating the feature back in time. So simply to compute `v[60]` and `w[60]`
This code I have no problem with and it does exactly the way I want it to do.

the problem is variable `mu10` I defined above as `mu10<-0.0067`

It should however be defined as: mu10(t)=alpha+beta*exp(gamma * t)
Where t should be al the sequences from `65.00000 64.91667 64.83333 64.75000......60.00000`
I want to replace my mu10 with mu10(t), the formula I defined here. mu10(t) shall then replace mu10 in the for-loop.

I want them to look like this:

```
v[t] <- v[t-1]+h*(-r*v[t-1]+b1+mu10[t]*(c10-v[t-1])+mu12*(w[t-1]-v[t-1]))
```

t on the left hand side should be the same as t in mu10(t) , perhaps obvious but just wanted to make clear.

I have tried a bit up and down but feels that it is not right. I have defined parameters as:

```
gamma<-0.044
alpha<-(-0.0073)
beta<-0.0009
```

**I simply need help to calculate `mu10(t)` in a smooth manner so it can be included in the for-loop.**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could just define mu10 as a function: `mu10 <- function(t) { return(alpha+beta*exp(gamma * t)) }`

Comment: Yes and no, thats the function, It does not work for you see so depends mu20 of mu10, so i get error in mu20. I want to replace mu10(t) instead of mu10. And mu10 shall be mu10(64.00000), mu10(64.91667). @MartinDabbelJuSmelter

Comment: why not put the calculation of mu10 (and mu20) _inside_ the loop?

Comment: In the above function you have to feed the corresponding value of `a`, not the `t` from your loop. So, in your notation it would then be `mu10(a[t])`.